# my c# program keeps increasing run time memory usages?

Tags: c#, server, client-server

My c# program keeps increasing run time memory usages. So it take about two - three days before it crashes. but I can see the memory usage slowly go up. In one day it goes from 723MB and the next day it is 1.62GB. I am running this C# program on a embedded device called a Moxa, so I do not have that much memory.

So I am sure the problem is in some new code I added, because I did not have this problem before.

here is the code :

```
private void SetupServer()
{
    AppendTextBox("Starting server ...");
    _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 502));
    _serverSocket.Listen(1);
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AppceptCallback), null);

}
private void AppceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
    __ClientSockets.Add(new SocketT2h(socket));
    //  list_Client.Items.Add(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

    AppendTextBox("client: " + __ClientSockets.Count.ToString());
    AppendTextBox("Client connected. . .");
    socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AppceptCallback), null);
}
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{

    Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    if (socket.Connected)
    {
        int received;
        try
        {
            received = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < __ClientSockets.Count; i++)
            {
                if (__ClientSockets[i]._Socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Equals(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()))
                {
                    __ClientSockets.RemoveAt(i);
                    AppendTextBox("Client : " + __ClientSockets.Count.ToString());
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        if (received != 0)
        {
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);

            int Registers_number = (((int)dataBuf[10] << 8) + (int)dataBuf[11]);
            int Message_Size = (Registers_number * 2) + 9;
            byte[] Message3 = new byte[Message_Size];
            TCPProcessing(dataBuf, Message3);


            string reponse = string.Empty;

            if (CiscoCB.Checked == true)
            {
                string Stemp = BitConverter.ToString(Message3);
                AppendTextBox(Stemp + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < __ClientSockets.Count; i++)
            {
                if (socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Equals(__ClientSockets[i]._Socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()))
                {
                    AppendTextBox("\n" + __ClientSockets[i]._Name + ": ");
                }
            }
            // reponse = "server da nhan" + text;
            Sendata(socket, Message3);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < __ClientSockets.Count; i++)
            {
                if (__ClientSockets[i]._Socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Equals(socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()))
                {
                    __ClientSockets.RemoveAt(i);
                    AppendTextBox("Client: " + __ClientSockets.Count.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
}
void Sendata(Socket socket, byte[] data)
{
    //  byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(noidung);
    socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new
    AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AppceptCallback), null);
}
private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    socket.EndSend(AR);
}
```

I think maybe it is not clearing the old connections but I am not sure.

Comment: If you are not sure, your next step would be to *get* sure. Nobody will run the program for you for days and scaffold test requests. You could create a log file and log each time you create a connection and when you stop using it. You can also log a reference counter.

Comment: What is the size of _buffer variable and where is it being initialized ? I suspect that you are not clearing it anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried calling the Dispose method of the Socket instances when you remove them from the __ClientSockets list.

Comment: what does AppendTextBox do?

Comment: Somehow your are not closing and disposing all the resources used. It could be the sockets or code not shown (maybe AppendTextBox?). Check the code you added and whatever that code uses clases that implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @ PaulF I do not see an option for Dispose.  How would that code look?

Comment: ok update, if I unplug the Ethernet wire my program will disconnect that client and if I click disconnect on that client my program will disconnect the program. how do I add a time out ? like if the server have not heard from a client after a while it disconnect from that client?

Comment: ok update,  when i unplug the Ethernet wire it does not disconnect. It does when I connect the program to a computer that run a modbus client, but then i connect to the cisco modem it does not. I think the cisco modem make a new connection everytime it pull data. I think the old connects are not being removed. any ideas ?